# SQL Server asterisk Extensions

Tags: sql-server, odbc, asterisk

I have some problem about extensions so that I have realtime asterisk SQL Server.

I have table `Extensions`:

```
id  context     exten   priority  app   appdata
---------------------------------------------------------
25  from_all    _270.   1         Dial  SIP/${EXTEN:0}@XX
```

This is how I have extensions but it isn't working when I am calling 27070 it is not calling and saying that

> 27070' rejected because extension not found in context 'from_all'.

When I am correcting `exten` in base `exten=27070`, it is working but I need to do like that after 270 any number or string must goo can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You also have setup correctly realtime.

i.e have be

```
 [somecontext]
 switch => Realtime/from_all@extensions
```

You can do debug and see EXACT queries which used in your dialplan.

Comment: how i can debug and see query?

Comment: asterisk -r,after that  core set debug 4

Comment: i have made it and /var/log/asterisk/messages and searched here about it but nothing there is same error .. not select nothing is there

Comment: You should see on same console. You also can add to messages if you want, see logger.conf. DEBUG IS OFFTOPIC on SO.